# How to get full url in javascript but without the host?

Tags: javascript

If I have a link like this

```
https://example.com:3000/sub/sub?a=1#f
```

how can I extract just

```
/sub/sub?a=1#f
```

?

Comment: `location.href.split("/").slice(3).join("/")` works back to 1999

Comment: Please show an attempt when asking a question, otherwise it sounds like please do my work for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `location.pathname + location.search + location.hash`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Answer (score 2):

```js
var getLocation = function(href) {
  var l = document.createElement("a");
  l.href = href;
  return l;
};
var l = getLocation("https://example.com:3000/sub/sub?a=1#f");

console.log(l.pathname + l.search + l.hash)
```

This extracts that part you have asked for.

Answer (score 2):

One of the alternative is `location.href.split('/').slice(3).join('/')`.
As url is always start with `http://{domain}/` or `https://{domain}/`, so if you split by `/`then what you want is array from 3rd element.

```js
var getLocation = function(href) {
  return href.split('/').slice(3).join('/');
};
var l = getLocation("https://example.com:3000/sub/sub?a=1#f");

console.log(l)
```

Or you can simply use `location.pathname + location.search + location.hash`

Answer (score -1):

One of the properties of the location global variable:

```
window.location.pathname
```

Comment: This doesn't get the query portion of the URI, or anything after the hash.